# No initial speedup on increasing the number of GPUs in a simulation on multiple GPUs

Tags: gpu, multi-gpu

I have used MPI+CUDA for this implementation of a computation on multiple GPUs. The GPU cluster used has 12 nodes each having 6 K40 GPUs. When I use 6 GPUs, they are from same computing node. However, if I measure the execution time by changing the number of GPUs, I get almost no speedup when I use 4 GPUs instead of 2, or 6 instead of 2. 
Below is the graph of execution time with the number of GPUs on two different input sizes. Strangely, the application achieves speed-up on increasing the number of GPUs in the system further. The initial flat part is unexplained though.

[image]

I also measured the communication time via nvprof. On adding GPUs, the number of calls to cudaMemcpy increase, as expected. However, surprisingly the average time for the completion of cudaMemcpy calls decreases with increasing GPUs. This should not happen as the size of each data transfer stays same, only the number of data transfers increase.

So there are mainly two questions:
1) Does anybody has some possible explanation for the initial flat part in the graph?
2) How is the cudaMemCpy time decreasing on adding more GPUs to the system?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Does your system use [SIMD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIMD)? That would explain why the average mem copy time goes down.

Comment: I guess the initial flat part means that your implementation does not scale on one node (using multiple GPUs of the same node) but it does scale when you pass messages thanks to MPI. About why it does not scale on one node, you probably stress some shared resource too much (for instance, the PCIe switch you use to send data from the host to the GPUs). I have no clue for the second part of your question.

Comment: Thanks Emilien for the comment. I have resolved the issue. Actually the graph was wrong. After every kernel launch, I had call to cudaDeviceSynchronize() for error checking, which was making the CPU  wait for launching kernel on next GPU until previous GPU finishes execution. And thus even though the computation was getting done by multiple GPUs, it was not getting done in parallel. When the program launches two MPI processes, it actually behaves like a 2 GPU implementation and not 12. The exact graph of this erroneous will look like a reverse step function.

Comment: Yes Austin, the system is SIMD. How does it explain the behaviour of  memcpy time? I still don't understand.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was premised on a programming error, and the data and hypotheses it contains are wrong. There is no answerable question here.